# How to change color of an image in an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I change the color of a `ImageView`?

I have a simple `png` and I want to change a color dynamically.

```
 private ImageView iconImage;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your question is a little generic. however, for some simple images you can try  in this way:

```
ColorFilter filter;
filter = new LightingColorFilter(0,Color.parseColor(variableColor));
iconImage.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Let me know

Comment: I added:  ImageView iconImage

Comment: yes of course you have to :)